# Is it possible to animate a mesh's geometry without using Shape Keys?

Tags: animation, mesh

I would like to animate a mesh's geometry without using [shape keys](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Techs/Shape/Shape_Keys). Is this possible?

Comment: As in changing the shape?

Comment: Yes, something like that, i need to 're-scale' a plane via geometry and animate it too..

Answer (score 31):

### AnimAll Addon

Yes, you can do this very easily by using the [*AnimAll*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/AnimAll) addon. "AnimAll" stands for "Animate All" because it enables you to animate many things that cannot normally be animated in Blender.

Here's how to use it:

1. First, open your User Preferences:
   *Info* header → *File* → *User Preferences*

   [image]
2. Click on "Addons" and in the search box, type animall, then enable it by clicking on the *Enable Addon* checkbox on the far right hand side of the addon:
   (**NOTE:** If you want to keep *AnimAll* enabled, click *Save User Settings* before closing the Preferences window)

   [image]
3. Now select the mesh you'd like to animate and go into *Edit* mode.
4. Now in the *Tools* panel (<kbd>T</kbd>), find the *AnimAll* section and enable *Points* -- this will allow you to animate the vertices of your mesh:
   (**NOTE:** If you are using 2.70, *AnimAll* will be in the *Animation* tab in the *Tools* panel. If you are using 2.69, it will be down at the very bottom of the *Tools* panel)

   [image]
5. In the *Timeline* window, make sure the green frame cursor is set to the frame you want the animation to begin. Here, it's set to frame 1:

   [image]
6. Now in the *AnimAll* options, click the *Insert (Keyframes)* button.
   (**NOTE:** This will insert keyframes for every single vertex in the mesh, regardless of whether they are selected or not, so if the mesh has lots of vertices, it may take a while before Blender is done inserting all the keyframes)

   [image]
7. In the *Timeline* window, move to the next important frame in your animation. Here, I'm moving to frame 75:

   [image]
8. Now alter your mesh's vertices as you like:

   [image]
9. Now insert keyframes for the vertices by again clicking *Insert (Keyframes)* button in *AnimAll*.
10. Now exit *Edit* mode and you can preview your animation by either clicking the *Play* button ( [image] ) in the *Timeline* window or with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

    [image]

---

**NOTE:** The [tutorial video on this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/AnimAll) describes how to use all the many other powerful features of *AnimAll*.

---

Comment: Great answer, thumbs up. Do you know if the animation would be imported into unity3d together with the mesh?

Comment: This statement is not true anymore: "NOTE: This will insert keyframes for every single vertex in the mesh, regardless of whether they are selected or not". You can select the ones you want in edit mode, make sure "Selected Only" option is on and keyframes are created only for selected ones.

Answer (score 16):

### Animation in blender, there are *lots* of options.

- You could use shape keys (they are very good for this kind of thing, but you don't want to so some other options)
- You could rig the mesh and then animate the bones.
- You could add hooks to part of your mesh, and then animate the hook.
- If you have a very dense mesh, then add a lattice modifier and add the hooks to the lattice.
- Or use a  mesh deform modifier and add the hooks to the cage mesh.
- For a different kind of control, add a curve modifier to the mesh, and again add hooks to the curve handles.
- You could use a displacement modifier and animate the texture.
- The AnimAll Addon is another option
- For any of the modifiers you can add and animate a vertex group to get more control.

There are more ways to animate meshes in blender, but this is just a sample. It should be noted that if you don't mind animating in edit mode, that the AnimAll addon can be used to save a step in place of the hooks in the above methods. If you would like more detail on any of these methods leave a comment.

Comment: Unless you're providing a reason why the thing requested by the OP _not_ to use _should_ be used, including it in the answer is probably not the best route. (I'm referring to mentioning shape keys again).

Comment: You could also use a Surface Deform Modifier and animate the surface using hooks... With so many overlapping solutions with their own overhead, it would be useful to explain what are the use cases of each one.

Answer (score 11):

Use the *Hook* tool. In edit mode, select a vertice, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>*> Hook to New Object*.

[image: Vertex Hook]

You can then easily animate the location of the *Hook* empty.

[image: Vertex Hook Animation]

You can also go to the mesh being deformed and add a **vertex group** if you want to have easy control of what vertices go where. Notice that you can also manually add hooks using the *Hook* modifier.

**One important thing to notice:**

> The hook modifier stores vertex indices from the original mesh to determine what to effect; this means that modifiers that generate geometry, like subsurf, should always be applied after the hook modifier; otherwise the generated geometry will be left out of the hook's influence.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use bones and weight paint:

[image]